# how to receive Json serializable object array in web api controller posted using httpclient

Tags: c#, .net, json, asp.net-web-api

I am sending data using `HttpClient` like below

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    streamWriter.Write(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(message).ToArray());
}
```

what would be the web api controller method parameter
i am going to use like below

```
public IHttpActionResult ReceivedMessages([FromBody] IList<char> messages)
```

Instead of `IList` i have tried `char[]` array and `string[]` array also. i am getting null value always.

But if i checked this `request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` i am receiving the value in string format but in controller class i am getting null

Comment: This does not make any sense, can you please explain why would you retrieve a list of `char` inside your Web API method? What is the type of the `message` object?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a copy of the type of message object at  the request sender, maybe,
a `MessageClass` , use the same type as a Request class `MessageClass` 
in Web api side and use

```
public IHttpActionResult ReceivedMessages([FromBody] List<MessageClass> messages);
```